# How to replace an object into an array?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Can anyone help me, I'm new to javascript, and I'm trying to overwrite an object inside the if-else condition. I have no idea on how to overwrite the existing object when i clicked the save button the output will change into a new object.

HTML template & controller:

```js
$scope.SubmitKeyword = function(key, new_keyword) {
  console.log(key, new_keyword)
  $scope.new_keyword = new_keyword;

  if ($scope.new_keyword == null || $scope.new_keyword == undefined || $scope.new_keyword == "") {
    alert('Invalid input!')
    return
  }

  angular.forEach($scope.new_campaign_keywords, function(v, k) {
    console.log(v, k)
    if (k == key) {
      if (v['orig_keyword'] == new_keyword) {
        alert('No Changes Found!')
        return
      } else {
        console.log('changes detected')
        var a = 0;
        angular.forEach($scope.campaigns, function(v1, k1) {
          a++
          console.log(a, k1)
          if (k1 == a) {
             //overwrite k1 into a new keyword
          }
          console.log(k1)
        })

      }
    }
  })

};
```

```html
<div layout="row">
  <form>
    <label style="padding-right:1em;font-weight:bold;" flex=3>{{$index + 1}} . </label>
    <label style="color:black;font-weight:bold;height: 20px;padding-bottom:1rem;white-space: nowrap;" flex=10>
       <span ng-show="!edit" >{{k}}</span>
       <input ng-show="edit == true;" ng-model="new" style="padding:4px; font-weight:bold; max-width: 500px;" />
       <button md-raised-button ng-click="edit = true;" style="font-size:15;border-radius:3px;border-width:1px;height:30px;width:80px;padding-left:2px;background-color:white; margin-left: 10px;" align="center center">Edit</button>
       <button md-raised-button ng-click="SubmitKeyword($index, new)" ng-hide="!edit" style="font-size:15;border-radius:3px; border-width:1px;height:30px;width:80px;padding-left:2px;background-color:white;" align="center center">Save</button>{{k1}}
    </label>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Please write more - which object, what should be an effect? I't difficult to understand what you want to do now.

Comment: I am not sure if you want to overwrite something (changing the original properties and/or values), or if you want to copy certain fields from an object to another object.

Comment: im about to change the original keyword into a new keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of forEach we can use reduce -:

```
$scope.campaigns = Object.keys($scope.campaigns).reduce((acc, value, key) => {
          console.log(a, k1)
          if (key == a) {
             //add k1 into acc into a new keyword
             acc[k1] = // your value;
          }
          // after defining k1 in acc return acc....
          return acc;
}, {});
```

Comment: This seems to be helpful, but in my case, I'm required to use only forEach. Thank you so much for your help.